# How to encode ZXING barcode to image

Tags: c#, asp.net, zxing

Good day all,

I want encode ZXING barcode in image format.The reason is want store at DB the image.
Below is my code.

```
      var brcode = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter();
                    var encOptions = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions() { Width = 2, Height = 2, Margin = 0 };
                    brcode.Options = encOptions;
                    brcode.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
                    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(brcode.Write(barcode));
```

it prompt error this error
"**Index was outside the bounds of the array**."

Please advise.

Advance thanks.

Comment: Where is `barcode` declared?

Comment: it variable :  var barcode = txtexpno.Text + txtmodel.Text + barcodeDate + userName + z;

Comment: Can use post the content of the variable "barcode"? I want to reproduce the error and fix it in the library.

Comment: eg: 90909090mydad160622admin2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hour testing and search, i found that
the issue is **ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;**

if i use `brcode.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_Code;`
it working fine.
barcode cannot transform to image in ZXING